# Column operations in LDPC generator matrix

Tags: forward-error-correction, ldpc

I'm trying to produce a generator matrix from a starting low density parity check matrix. There are lots of references on the topic (including this Signal Processing Stack Overflow answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/7798/how-to-compute-generator-matrix-from-a-parity-check-matrix)). They make sense, with the exception of one problem I'm having.

My resource is the book *Error Correction Coding: Mathematical Methods and Algorithms* by Todd K. Moon. In it, there is a section that describes this that I will replicate below, and then highlight the part I'm stuck on.

> For a code specified by a parity check matrix $A$, it is expedient for encoding purposes
>   to determine the corresponding generator matrix $G$. A systematic generator matrix may
>   be found as follows. Using Gaussian elimination ***with column pivoting as necessary*** (with
>   binary arithmetic) determine an $M$ x $M$ matrix $A^{-1}$ so that
>
> $$H = A_p^{-1} A = [I \quad A_2].$$
>
> (If such a matrix $A$, does not exist, then $A$ is rank deficient, $r = \mathrm{rank}(A) < M$. In this
>   case, form $H$ by truncating the linearly dependent rows from $A_p^{-1} A$. The corresponding
>   code has $R = K/N > (N - M)/N$, so it is a higher rate code than the dimensions of $A$
>   would suggest.) Having found $H$, form
>
> $$G=\begin{bmatrix}A_2 \\ I\end{bmatrix}.$$
>
> Then $H G = 0$, so $A_p H G = A G = 0$, so $G$ is a generator matrix for $A$. While $A$ may be
>   sparse (as discussed below), neither the systematic generator $G$ nor $H$ is necessarily sparse.

Here's the problem I'm running into:
I start with $A$ and do Gauss-Jordan elimination in $\mathbb{G_2}$ to get it into reduced row echelon form.

Sometimes the matrix I've been given (I'm not designing it, have to use what I'm given) can't be put into that form with solely row operations.

It requires actually swapping the order of some columns (is that what he means by "column-pivoting" in the reference above?). Everything in me screams that's wrong, but it turns out if I just do the same thing on the decoding side it works out.

But then I'm left with the conundrum that when I go to decode something encoded with this parity check matrix I have to know how the matrix columns were reordered on the transmit side.

Basically I have to re-do the generator matrix, which is by far the slowest part of my process (I'm going to make some improvements there though, using the QC-LDPC structure of the parity matrix).

It seems bizarre to me that a designed system would put in a parity check matrix that requires column reordering to work.

Is there something I'm missing? For what it's worth I also have the example matlab code from the aforementioned book and this is what he does (column reordering and then re-applying that re-orderying on the decode side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Everything in me screams that's wrong, but it turns out if I just do the same thing on the decoding side it works out.

Why? That just means you *reorder* some bits. On the other end, when you revert that reordering, that's an operation that changes nothing about the code itself.

In fact, your system almost certainly has an interleaver, anyway, so you such reordering operations are absolutely integral to how it works!

> the conundrum that when I go to decode something encoded with this parity check matrix I have to know how the matrix columns were reordered on the transmit side.

What's surprising about that? Your receiver needs to have a decoder matching the encoder.

Don't forget that swapping columns is just a permutation matrix that you apply your data. Done!

> It seems bizarre to me that a designed system would put in a parity check matrix that requires column reordering to work.

Why? You say that, but you don't *argue* based on anything about that. In fact, many coding-theory proofs are based on random codes...

Again, imagine your reordering operations as permutation matrices that you just use after / before applying the parity check / generator matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was just hoping to be sure that I'm interpreting the process correctly. Just to respond to one of your comments, indeed there is interleaving and it's no problem to re-order bits. The issue is that the interleaver has a low cost, known equation. In this instance I need to know how the given parity check matrix must be re-ordered in order to decode. That seems pretty inefficient, given that the relationship isn't known *a priori* like with interleaving. Perhaps I can create a LUT or use memoization though.

Comment: @EricC. $HG = 0 \iff A_p H G=AG=0$, both $H$ and $A$ are the parity check matrix of $G$. Just use your original parity check matrix.

Comment: @AlexTP nice argument using the syndrome.

Comment: @AlexTP There's something I'm still confused on though. I'm under the impression I can't represent column reordering via a left-multiplied matrix. Can't that only be done by a matrix multiplied on the right? That means that I can't actually get the systematic form of $A$ by a left multiplied $A_p^{-1}$ matrix. Second, when I tried just using the original parity check matrix I couldn't decode, I had to reorder the columns like I did on the transmit side. Third, that's what his example code does as well.

Comment: In general, it is true that column permutation cannot be done with left multiplication: you can see it by using block presentation. For your second point, use this matlab code to generate $G$ matrix:

    `H = H.';
    numInfBits = size(H,2) - size(H,1);
    Hgf = gf(H);
    H1 = Hgf(:,1:numInfBits);
    H2 = Hgf(:,numInfBits+1:end);
    Pgf = (H2\(-H1))';
    P = double(Pgf.x);
    G = [eye(numInfBits), P];
    G = G.';`

If this code fails, simply your $H$ is not a PCM for systematic code.
...

Comment: I don't understand your third point, which "his example code"?

Finally, if you are working with the NR QC-LDPC, these codes are certainly well defined and you will not run to this problem.

Comment: @AlexTP interesting. To respond to your last point, perhaps that means I have a bug in my code that produces $H$ using the protograph and the table in the spec. Perhaps I translated something incorrectly. Because it's definitely that spec that I'm running into this problem with. The matrix doesn't seem to be able to get into systematic form without column reordering.

Comment: To reply to your other question, the snippet that I quoted in the OP was from the book by Moon. He has some example Matlab code and in the Gauss Jordan elimination it looks for the case in which the systematic form isn't reachable and swaps columns in order to get there. It then keeps track of the swapped columns and reorders the original parity check matrix in the same way before doing decoding.

Comment: @EricC. OK try the matlab code, I have used it for all Base Graph 2 and some Base Graph 1 matrix without seeing problem. Note that the first and last commands `H=H.'` and `G=G.'` are to adapt to your codeword dimension, and maybe unnecessary.

Comment: @AlexTP Thanks for the code, to be honest that was my missing link and I didn't realize Matlab/octave had galois field operations like that and a matrix left division for galois fields. So it turns out that my problem is the algorithm that I implemented (I'm working in C++) for Gauss-Jordan elimination couldn't find the answer Matlab did. It thought it was only solvable by swapping some columns. Now, any tips on a good GF(2) GJ solver I could use, or what algorithm Matlab uses?

Comment: @EricC. The MATLAB leftmatrix divide is the shortcut of `mldivide()`, which is a collection of solver for linear equations, whose algo description can be found at https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html

In your case where the matrix is not square, it is QR algo that is used. https://fr.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/qrsolver.html

Comment: @EricC. However, if efficiency of NR LDPC encoder is your concern, using $G$ is a very bad idea because $G$ is not sparse. I suggest trying parity check matrix based generator to exploit the $H$ sparseness, e.g. by using the algo of paper https://www.mdpi.com/2079-9292/8/6/668/pdf

Comment: Thanks @AlexTP , I'm actually in the process as we speak of implementing that very paper. Incidentally, the older version of octave that choked on my BG2 matrix worked fine using the block decomposition method in that paper. I do love how optimized the paper routines are, but it seems that even just doing the suggested block decomposition and inverting the one $B$ matrix mentioned in the paper would be an enormous speedup in and of itself. Thoughts? Are you finding with that method that there are no rank deficient parity matrices using the spec for BG1 and BG2?

Comment: @EricC. I don't understand what you mean by "inverting $B$". If you are trying to solve the linear equations, which are represented by the parity check matrix and whose solution is the desired codeword, it is essentially the method of the paper.
I used the method of the paper for all BG2 and some BG1 and it did work well.

Comment: @AlexTP, sorry, I wasn't clear there. I'm implementing the full version of the paper. But I was just saying that even only halfway implementing it would lead to a significant speedup. It block decomposes $H$ into $[A \, B \: 0; C_1 \, C_2 \, I]$ and multiplies that by $[c \, p_a \, p_c]^T$ and sets it to 0. You can solve that top row for $p_a$ by inverting $B$ (although you wouldn't actually invert, instead doing back-substitution). But I digress.

Comment: The bigger issue I'm seeing with that paper is that it shows an example for BG1 and assumes a form for the $B$ matrix. Looking at the spec that form is *usually* correct, except for when the set index ($i_{LS}$) is 6. For BG2 the form is different when $i_{LS} = 3$ or $i_{LS} = 7$. It's no big deal, I was able to use the same process in the paper and arrive at similarly low-cost calculations. But it is odd. Perhaps they added those variations later? The most frustrating one is for BG1 and set index 6 one of the values of $V_{i,j} = 105$, instead of the normal 0 or 1. But it's doable.

Comment: @EricC. Sorry since it is nearly a year I worked on this, I don't remember these implementation-specific stuffs. And yes, it is true that you need to modify the paper routine to cope with these particular $i_{LS}$. The idea behind this oddity is that these 5G NR BG are defined to be rate-compatible, i.e. for puncturing only a subset of the PCM is needed, and highly-parallelizable. I heard anecdotes that these BG are found by exhaustive search. Unfortunately, I cannot confirm it since I was not in the loop of the BG design.